# RequestMapping with slashes and dot

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have to support following URL format

`/service/country/city/addr1/addr2/xyz.atom`
`/service/country/city/addr1/addr2/addr3/xyz.atom`

where `country` and `city` can be mapped to `@PathVariable` but after that the path can be dynamic with multiple slashes. The end part will have `.atom` or similar.

I tried following, but none of the options seem to be working

- Wildcard

  `@RequestMapping(value="/service/{country}/{city}/**")`
- Regex

  `@RequestMapping(value="/service/{country}/{city}/{addr:.+}")`
- UseSuffixPatternMatch

  Override method in Config class

  ```
   @Override
   public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
   }
  ```

Looks like combination of slash and dots don't work with above solutions. 
I keep getting `406` for non-matching Accept header, or `404`

Comment: Request to comment the reason for downvote

Comment: Hi, i tried your first option, RequestMapping(value="/service/{country}/{city}/**"), and works for dynamic URL with multiple slashes

Comment: 406 has nothing to do with the path. It seems you had it right but your controller is unable to deliver the content in the required format.

Comment: @cralfaro it does not work for me if the last value has dot

Comment: Please refer to the following

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex

Comment: Your request mappings are fine. Add more details about your configurations, project structure and other relevant codes

Comment: I can confirm that your wildcard value for the RequestMapping works with dots. Both the paths given by you work on the wildcard... and you can still get the rest of the URI from the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most dynamic approach would be to use `MatrixVariable` to manage the list of addresses but it is not applicable in your context since the paths cannot be modified as far as I understand from your question.

The best thing you can do to manage your dynamic path is to proceed in two steps:

1. Set a `RequestMapping` that extracts all the data except the addresses
2. Extract the addresses manually in the method

So for the first step you will have something like that:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/service/{country}/{city}/**/{file}.atom")
    public String service(@PathVariable String country, 
         @PathVariable String city, @PathVariable String file,
         HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
```

This mapping matchs with all the required paths and allows to extract the country, the city and the file name.

In the second step we will use what has been extracted to get the addresses by doing something like this:

```
String path = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
path = path.substring(String.format("/service/%s/%s/", country, city).length(), 
                      path.length() - String.format("%s.atom", file).length());
String[] addrs = path.split("/");
```

1. First we extract from the request the full path
2. Then we remove what we have already extracted which are here the beginning and the end of the path
3. Then finally we use `String.split` to extract all the addresses

At this level you have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the closest I could get. Only thing that required change is the extension at the end, which is variable in my case. Hence the final request mapping looks like `@RequestMapping(value="/service/{country}/{city}/**/{addr}.{extn}")`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/service/{country}/{city}/{addr:[a-z]+\\\\.(atom|otherExtensions)}")
```

Just have to specify the complete regex format wherein you are expecting an extension at the end of the url such as atom, since this will be interpreted by default as MediaType by Spring.

another solution is specify the accepted MediaTypes

```
@RequestMapping(value="/service/{country}/{city}/{addr}", consumes = {MediaType.ATOM, MediaType...})
```

You can create custom MediaTypes if it is not predefined in Spring.